# Find out if a user has access to Microsoft Graph API for Excel

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to use Microsoft Graph API to write some data to an Excel Spreadsheet.
This works quite fine when I use my MS 365 developer subscription.

When I'm trying to use any other account (work account, personal account, my private account) I get a lot of different errors (see at the bottom).

Microsoft states [in this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/excel?view=graph-rest-1.0) that the Excel API is only available for files stored in the "business platform".

> Note: Support for workbooks stored in OneDrive Consumer platform is still not available. At this time, only the files stored in business platform are supported by Excel REST APIs.

How am I supposed to identify if a user has access to the Excel API or not? The errors I am getting are not very clear about this. I assume these errors could also appear for various other reasons.
Showing the error messages to the user doesn't seem like a good option.
Is there an API endpoint to get infos about the users license maybe?

---

**Edit:**
I just found out about the `/me/licenseDetails` request.
This request returns a list of service plans.
Is this the service plan I need to be looking for?

```
{
  "servicePlanId": "5dbe027f-2339-4123-9542-606e4d348a72",
  "servicePlanName": "SHAREPOINTENTERPRISE",
  "provisioningStatus": "Success",
  "appliesTo": "User"
},
```

Are there other service plans which allow the user to use the Excel API?

---

Here are the errors I get (also in Graph Explorer):

My private MS account:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "FileOpenUserUnauthorized",
    "message": "You do not have permissions to open this file in the browser.",
    "innerError": {
      "code": "unauthorizedUncategorized",
      "message": "Required authentication information for the resource is either missing or invalid.",
      "innerError": {
        "code": "FileOpenUserUnauthorized",
        "message": "You do not have permissions to open this file in the browser."
      },
      "date": "2024-02-22T12:31:15",
      "request-id": "a8667d4d-951f-40ae-b1d9-27f497c79e86",
      "client-request-id": "38e49435-89e8-9288-6251-17647e6a529f"
    }
  }
}
```

Work account:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Tenant does not have a SPO license.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2024-02-22T12:37:35",
      "request-id": "14dd6a89-9724-4521-bd3e-133f645548c2",
      "client-request-id": "c00b949a-d401-82ab-a858-9d9a6bc51c40"
    }
  }
}
```

Personal account (associated with the work account):

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "generalException",
    "message": "General Exception While Processing",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2024-02-22T12:40:38",
      "request-id": "af43b4c2-2d2e-41f1-8ad8-71280f65aa8b",
      "client-request-id": "52988411-9b43-646e-2787-a7867c69b983"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I found this list but haven't gotten any smarter https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/users/licensing-service-plan-reference